# How does Office 2008 for Mac store its Recent items?

Tags: macos, ms-office, preferences

I don't have access to Office 2008, but require the information for a project I'm working on. I'm mainly interested in Word, Excel and Powerpoint.

This is the information I have gathered so far...

The preference file is: `~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.office.plist`

The property keys take the form:

`2008\File Aliases\{APP}{n}`

`2008\MRU Access Date\{APP}{n}`

where `{APP}` represents an Office application, and `{n}` represents a number starting from 0.

The applications are represented by the following values:

`MSWD` (Word)

`XCEL` (Excel)

What value represents PowerPoint?

In the property list I've seen, the numbers represented by `{n}` range from **0**-**10** (11 items).

Is 10 the limit? or is this unrestrained?

Finally, I've noticed that Office 2011 does not add its Recent Items to the Apple System menu:

`Apple` -> `Recent Items`

Is Office 2008 the same?

Comment: 10 recent documents is the default on Mac OS X. Edit `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist` (entry named `NSRecentDocumentsLimit`) to see if Office uses this setting for its limit.

Comment: This may provide a clue, or provide additional information in any answer. But it is worth taking into account that Office applications don't just display recent items in the menu, they also display them in a window that appears when you start one of the office applications. Another approach to gathering this info could be if someone could save, say 13 dummy documents, then look in ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.office.plist they should be able to see how many "File Alieses" were stored agains that application. @Daniel Beck

Comment: It appears that PowerPoint is represented by the value `PPT3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least on my machine, this is what I'm seeing:

1. PPT3 does appear to be the PowerPoint value
2. I have lots of items. MSWD0, MSWD1, but then also MSWD99, MSWD109, etc. [image: Screenshot of plist]
3. Interestingly enough, it looks like PowerPoint adds items to `Apple -> Recent Items`, but Word and Excel do not. Which seems crazy, but that's what's happening on my machine.