# OPEN RECENT FILE command vanished in Word for Mac Office 2008

Tags: macos, ms-office, word-processor

I am running OS Maverick 10.9.3 on my Mac Book Pro and have worked happily on Office 2008 through several versions of OSX. After a recent "update" by Apple, my "Open Recent Files" vanished from my File pull-down menu. An unfamiliar "Open from Document Connection" now appears there. I have no idea what "Open from Document Connection" means. My "Open Recent File" command was important for me because I work on many multiple projects, and I want that command back. Can anyone tell me how my Open Recent File command vanished and how I can get that back?

Comment: that would be a setting in the MS office preferences.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like your Office Preference file got damaged.

Look in Office Preference setting to make sure the show recent files is checked.

[image: office recent]

If it is and you still don't see them, the Reset your Office preferences:

There are few procedures [available online describing](http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/display/istcontrib/Reset+Microsoft+Office+preferences+to+the+default+on+Macintosh) how to, and where the [files are stored](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/8219/46541).